# chrome.debugger commands doesn't affect sub frames

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to make a chrome extension that will use the chrome.debugger api('Log.enable'), but I found that iframes are not affected by the chrome.debugger commands.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service_worker.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "permissions": ["debugger", "tabs"]
}
```

**service_worker.js**

```
//enable Log domain
const onDebuggerAttach = async tabId => {
  await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId}, 'Log.enable');
  chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onDebugEvent);
};

//get console messages
const onDebugEvent = (debuggeeId = {}, message, params = {}) => {
  switch (message) {
    case 'Log.entryAdded':
      handleConsoleMessage(debuggeeId.tabId, params);
      break;     
    default:
      break;
  }
};

// tabId is current tab id
chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId }, '1.3', onDebuggerAttach.bind(null, tabId));
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId}, 'Log.enable');
```

How do I make the chrome.debugger commands work on all the tab frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-of-process iframes are separate targets. You need to use autoAttachRelated or setAutoAttach to work with subtargets. See https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-autoAttachRelated

Comment: Can you provide short example of how to use autoAttachRelated or setAutoAttach? I can`t understand what is targetId.

Comment: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/debugger_auto_attach_permissions/background.js