# Reading the user's console errors from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-console

I am creating a small extension for personal use that should help me analyze errors using an API I made. In order to do that it requires read access to the console of the active tab. Is there a way to achieve that? I tried overriding the console methods but then found out the extension's js is isolated from the tab's, so kinda lost here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it in [the MAIN world](/a/9517879) or use chrome.debugger ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814346/chrome-debugger-commands-doesnt-affect-sub-frames)).